# CASE in WHERE clause? Filter query by different column depending a value SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to use a different column in my `WHERE` clause depending on the date being passed in. So for example, I'd like to do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG = 1
AND 
   CASE WHEN @param < '1/1/2015' THEN
      COLUMN_1 = 'Warehouse'
   ELSE
      COLUMN_2 = 'Warehouse, CA'
```

As of now I'm handling it like this:

```
IF @param < '1/1/2015' THEN

  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 AND COLUMN_1 = 'Warehouse'

ELSE

  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 AND COLUMN_2 = 'Warehouse, CA'
```

But I assume there has to be a better solution than maintaining the same query twice?

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use simple `AND`, `OR` operations to get what you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 
      AND (
       (@param < '1/1/2015' AND COLUMN_1 = 'Warehouse')
        OR
       (@param >= '1/1/2015' AND COLUMN_2 = 'Warehouse, CA')
      )
```

If `@param < '1/1/2015'`, then the `WHERE` clause becomes:

```
ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 AND COLUMN_1 = 'Warehouse'
```

otherwise, in case when `@param >= '1/1/2015'`, the `WHERE` clause becomes:

```
ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 AND COLUMN_2 = 'Warehouse, CA'
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

You can express this as:

```
WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 AND
      ((@param < '1/1/2015' AND COLUMN_1 = 'Warehouse') OR
       (@param >= '1/1/2015' AND COLUMN_1 = 'Warehouse, CA')
      );
```

(Perhaps with an additional check for `NULL` `@param` values.)

Note on performance, however:  when you put this in one query, you run the risk of SQL Server choosing a worse execution plan.  So, if you have an index on `(ACTIVE_FLAG, COLUMN_1)`, then using two queries or dynamic SQL might produce a better execution plan.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the same thing:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG = 1 AND 
    ( (@param <  '1/1/2015' and COLUMN_1 = 'Warehouse')
   OR (@param >= '1/1/2015' and COLUMN_2 = 'Warehouse, CA')
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!